# Disable "Recent Download History Popup" in Crome Using Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

How to disable recently downloaded history popup when we download a file from crome in Java Selenium[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGE8a.png)?

I didnt get any "options.addArguments" to block this feature. This is the latest feature(after 110 might be) added by crome

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.